# Typescript or babel plugin to transform a ES6 class to function with scoped variables acting as private properties pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, transpiler

Background: Not so long ago functions with scoped variables acting as private properties or methods was an extremely efficient way to create classes in JavaScript. Today's standards is to use the more verbose and file size inefficient approach of using `prototype` and the `this` keyword. Also the modern approach it's less flexible.

Is there any transform plugin to convert a ES6 class into a function with scoped variables acting as instance private variables? In code:

```js
class MyClass { 
  private myProp = "hello "; // or #myProp with new proposed syntax
  private myProp2 = "World"; // or #myProp2 with new proposed syntax

  print() {
    console.log(this.myProp + this.myProp2);
  }
}
```

into:

```js
function MyClass() {
  var self = this,
      myProp = "hello ",
      myProp2 = "World";

  self.print = function() {
    console.log(myProp + myProp2);
  }
}
```

Any suggestion?

**Note**: I'm aware of how JavaScript prototype works and that the second approach doesn't use it. The whole point of this question is to find an *transpilation* alternative to the prototype pattern as shown above, which is 100% valid and equivalent to the typical use cases of classes. I.e. `myClass.print();`.

**Update 2**: For those considering the memory footprint they're right. The JavaScript engine performance is not a problem since the not-so-old and modern engines take this approaches into account.

**Update 3**: Also, this pattern can offer class inheritance, public/private static methods and it's fully compatible with the "instanceof" operator on the base class and the parent classes.

Comment: Those are not equivalent. `print` goes on `MyClass.prototype`, not on the instance.

Comment: TS transforms to es5 syntax means that _private_ variables are obfuscated, and not explicitly private (e.g. `_privateVar`) - You could technically ensure those variables are only defined within functional or lexical scope - but i assume that is enough to help for now

Comment: Why though? All things being equal, let the compiler do its thing. Typescript has a solution you already know for truly private instance variables. And too much `this.` in your code will never be why your library is too big, especially with gzipping of JS assets. Lastly, typescript should be compatible with skipping the `class` keyword entirely and having a constructor function with a manually setup prototype.

Comment: @AlexWayne I agree on your statement but I have to disagree with "Typescript has a solution you already know for truly private instance variables". Typescript doesn't (officially) offer any transformation pattern to achieve "truly private instance variables/properties/methods" when transforming a ESNext class into ES5 "class".

Comment: "*the more verbose and file size inefficient approach*" - what? Your second snippet is longer than your first. (Btw, I think you meant `myProp` instead of `self.myProp`)

Comment: "*Also, this pattern can offer class inheritance*" - no, `class extends` won't work, `super` calls won't work. But why not just write the code style from the second snippet directly?

Comment: "Your second snippet is longer than your first." -> You're comparing it wrong. Look at what Typescript does.

Comment: @Bergi  _"no, class extends won't work, super calls won't work."_ Yes, it does work. You can easily inherit (by extending) parent public methods. Parent class inheritance would be just a scoped variable with a parent instance + extending self.

Comment: @Bergi _"But why not just write the code style from the second snippet directly?"_ Good question. Typescript makes it difficult to make use of this pattern and I was hoping someone has developed a transformed for that pattern so the developer keeps using the fancy class construction.

Comment: @JoséCabo If the typescript transpiler output is too verbose, you should consider using ES6 or higher as the target language.

Comment: @JoséCabo Typescript does support [_truly_ private instance fields on classes with the `#foo` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields)